# How Do I Go About Transposing/Cutting Columns into Rows in R

Tags: r, reshape, reshape2

I am working with a large dataset on country level data that is in country-year format and appears in the following form (abridged for ease):

```
Country     Variable of Interest  Year
Bolivia     5                     1990
Bolivia     6                     1991
Bolivia     7                     1992
Cambodia    8                     1990
Cambodia    9                     1991
Cambodia    10                    1992
Russia      11                    1990
Russia      12                    1991
Russia      13                    1992
```

Due to a collaboration with a colleague, how do I get the data into this form?:

```
Country   1990    1991   1992
Bolivia    5        6     7
Cambodia   8        9     10
Russia     11       12    13
```

I'm using R version 2.15.2 and using the library WDI to poll the World Bank for the information.  I'm attaching my code as it stands so far that will work for a single country.  I will then paste the code when I try to do it for all countries.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

```
library(WDI)
x<-WDI(country="US",indicator="NY.GDP.MKTP.CD",start = 1980, end=2012)
a<-as.matrix(x$country)
b<-x$year
x<-as.data.frame(t(x))
colnames(x)<-b
x<-x[-1:-2,][-2,]
x<-x[,order(ncol(x):1]
a<-a[1,]
rownames(x)<-a
x
```

The change for when I try to change to all countries is changing the argument "US" to "all" in WDI.

I appreciate any and all help on this!  Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `reshape2` package:

Assuming your `data.frame` is `df` (I changed the second column name to `Interest`):

```
require(reshape2)
# use dcast as:
dcast(df, Country ~ Year, value.var="Interest")


#    Country 1990 1991 1992
# 1  Bolivia    5    6    7
# 2 Cambodia    8    9   10
# 3   Russia   11   12   13
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 reshape(dfrm, timevar="Year", direction="wide", idvar='Country')
#-------------
   Country Variable_of_Interest.1990 Variable_of_Interest.1991 Variable_of_Interest.1992
1  Bolivia                         5                         6                         7
4 Cambodia                         8                         9                        10
7   Russia                        11                        12                        13
```

If you wanted to fix the names to your liking then setNames could be useful:

```
setNames( reshape(dfrm, timevar="Year", direction="wide", idvar='Country'), 
           c("Country", unique(dfrm$Year) )  )
#--------------
   Country 1990 1991 1992
1  Bolivia    5    6    7
4 Cambodia    8    9   10
7   Russia   11   12   13
```

Note that column names with leading digits are not really valid unless quoted.